# How to solve this by-default error Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'

Tags: javascript, deployment, console

This error comes in my console. is there any code which i should place in my index.html to get rid of this?

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.

I wanted no errors in the console, but this error is by default in the console

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error showed up for me when using http://192.168.1.100/ as URL for local dev. Changing to http://localhost fixed the issue for me.